# delete every second element until one is left ruby

Tags: ruby

I am trying to delete every 2nd element until only one is left.
So it goes starting from 1 skip, delete, skip, delete and so on.

so far I had something like this

```
   l =* (1..10)
until  l.length == 1
l = l.each_slice(2).map(&:first)
puts l
end
```

There are several problems with this.
and each_slice is actually just picking every 2nd one and not deleting every second element.
the final result should be 5.

I am looking not necessarily for the prettiest solution but for the easiest and simplest.

I appreciate your help

Comment: You should use lower-case `l` because capitalized words are considered constants in Ruby.  Then the line inside your loop should just be `l = l.each_slice(2).map(&first)` and it would work, right?  Could you be more specific about what is not working and why?

Comment: the problem is that it always starts again from the beginning while I rather would have it go continuously.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
l =* (1..10)
until l.length == 1
  l.rotate!(2).pop
end
puts "#{l}"
```

The rotation, I guess since I am not sure how it is implemented, would slow it down. Although, I would rather create a doubly-circular linked list for this problem because this is a special case of the famous [Flavius Josephus problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Josephus_problem).

HTH

Edit: one-liner as suggested by @MarkThomas

```
l =* (1..10)
l.rotate!(2).pop until l.length.one?
puts "#{l}"
```

Comment: This looks good.
Harsh Gupta, could you kindly explain how the rotate works here? So I know rotate pus the first element to the end but you wrote rotate(2) so it puts the last 2 elements to the end? How did you come up with that. Also, pop always deletes the last item so you basically give always the second number to be deleted at the end is that correct?

Comment: `rotate(2)` pushes the first 2 elements from array to the end. And yes, you are right about the general idea.

Comment: This would make a nice concise one-liner: `l.rotate!(2).pop until l.length.one?`

Answer (score 0):

I would probably go with:

```
l = *(1..10)
l.delete_if.with_index { |_, i| i.even? } until l.one?
```

Comment: Just passing by and don't know ruby ... but you should probably add an explanation of your code to your answer.